# CakePHP 2.3 - Can I call a custom url via AJAX when using Js Helper

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

UPDATE: This specific project is built in CakePHP, but other websites on the server are already using the same file upload methods from the 'upload.php' file. I want to know if it is possible to use an existing PHP script WITHOUT incorporating it into any controllers of the Cake project.

I am trying to call a script "upload.php", located in the 'webroot' directory of my CakePHP project, when a form "#image_upload_form" is submitted. The code I am using to override the upload form's original action is:

```
$data = $this->Js->get('#image_upload_form')->serializeForm(array('isForm' => true, 'inline' => true));
    $this->Js->get('#image_upload_form')->event(
        'submit',
        $this->Js->request(array('http://example.com/upload.php?modal=1&z='.microtime(), 'update' => '#content', 'data' => $data, 'dataType' => 'html', 'async' => true, 'dataExpression'=>true,'method' => 'POST', 'cache' => false, 'success' => 'javascript:bind_view_dialog_triggers("#view_dialog ");')
    )
);
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

My problem is that when the submit button is clicked on this form, the url that is called is relative to my current controller, for example:

```
http://example.com/controller/view/http://example.com/upload.php...
```

How can I use the JsHelper to rewrite the url so that it is not generated relative to the page it is being called from? I would like to keep my other php file (upload.php) as-is (a stand alone script) if at all possible.

Comment: Why you are doing this in CakePHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out by reviewing the documentation for the JsBaseEngineHelper->request(): http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-JsBaseEngineHelper.html#_request

The syntax provided there is:

```
$this-Js->request($url, $options)
```

where the $url can be a string or an array, and options is an array.
The mistake I was making was that my $url was being passed as part of the options array. This caused the JsHelper to append it to the current view's url when placing the request.

I've updated my request line to read:

```
$this->Js->request('http://example.com/upload.php?z='.microtime(),array('update' => '#upload-image-parent', 'data' => $data, 'dataType' => 'html', 'async' => true, 'dataExpression'=>true,'method' => 'POST', 'cache' => false))
```

This is now sending the form data to the 'example.com/upload.php' script, which is what I wanted.